# How to print just the content of the help string of a specific argument of ArgParse

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to access the help strings for specific arguments of the argument parser library object?

I want to print the help string content if the option was present on the command line. *Not* the complete help text that Argument Parser can display via ArgumentParser.print_help .

So something along those lines:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-d", "--do_x", help='the program will do X')

if do_x:
    print(parser.<WHAT DO I HAVE TO PUT HERE?>('do_x')
```

And this is the required behavior

$program -d

> the program will do X

Comment: So do you just want to make it print `the program will do X` whenever the argument `-d` is parsed? Or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `parser._option_string_actions` which is mapping between option strings (`-d` or `--do_x`) and [`Action` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action-classes). `Action.help` attribute holds the help string.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-d", "--do_x", action='store_true',
                    help='the program will do X')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.do_x:
    print(parser._option_string_actions['--do_x'].help)
    # OR  print(parser._option_string_actions['-d'].help)
```

Answer (score 3):

`parser._actions` is a list of the `Action` objects.  You can also grab object when creating the parser.

```
a=parser.add_argument(...)
...

If args.do_x:
      print a.help
```

Play with `argparse` in an interactive session.  Look at `a` from such an assignment.

Comment: thanks for answering, the one from @falsetru seems more straightforward to me but I guess this is just my style

Comment: Some people don't like using `._` attributes.  But they also complain that `a=parser...` isn't documented either.

Comment: I agree, it would be better to have it in the API as a function. The parser._option_string_actions['--do_x'].help looks more self-explanatory and we don't need to create additional variables. However hardcoded text strings are always fragile (+internationalisation as well!). So on the other hand the a=parser... approach may be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, so adding an answer to expand upon @hpaulj's answer

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Example Description"
)

help_text = {}

# custom function to capture help text to display to user
def add_argument(argument, argument_type, help_string, default=None):
    global parser, help_text
    if default is not None:
        ret = parser.add_argument(
            argument,
            type=argument_type,
            help=help_string,
            default=default,
        )
    else:
        ret = parser.add_argument(
            argument,
            type=argument_type,
            help=help_string,
        )
    
    # starts with --, remove it
    if "--" == argument[0:2]:
        argument = argument[2:]
    # starts with -, remove it
    if "-" == argument[0]:
        argument = argument[1:]
    
    # capture help text
    help_text[argument] = ret.help
    return

add_argument(
    "file",
    argument_type=str,
    help_string="Path to file to parse",
)

add_argument(
    "--log_file",
    argument_type=str,
    help_string="Log file",
    default="LogFile.csv",
)


args = parser.parse_args()

print("")
print("------------------------------------------------------")
# print("\n\nArguements received are:")
# print(args)

print("---------------- Script Parameters -------------------")
for args_key in vars(args):
    print(f"\n{args_key}: {getattr(args, args_key)}\n({help_text[args_key]})")
print("------------------------------------------------------")
print("")
```